# Create svg without using public Url

Tags: jquery, svg

Hi i am using svg to draw lines but my problem is i am using public url's to draw line `var svgnode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

```
        svgnode.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "overflow:none");

        var defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "defs");
        var marker = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "marker");
        var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "path");`
```

how to achieve the same without using pubic urls

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i am having svg.js file how can i use that file to draw svg elements using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a URL, it just looks like one, it's actually a namespace. w3c chose namespaces to have the format of URLs but there's actually no connection between them otherwise.

Comment: so you meant that even there is no internet connection available it should work right?

Comment: correct, namespaces do not imply internet connectivity is required.

Comment: Is this because the namespaces are baked into the browser? Because if so, if they at some point are not anymore, would you need an internet connection?